# Specifying a new template for Django Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates, django-views

I have been looking around the web for a solution but I cant seem to find a valid solution.

I am trying to override the default "index" page for a specific model. I know you can change the URL setting in the project's url.py folder like this :

```
url(r'^items/(?P<itemId>\d+)/$', 'items.views.itemDetail')
```

While the above URL mapping works fine and the itemDetail(request) method gets called correctly, something like this :

```
url(r'^admin/homepage/$', 'homepage.views.index'),
```

doesn't seem to work. I know this doesn't work because of this line:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

Every attempt at changing the above line's pattern causes errors unless I go directly to admin/homepage. So the default admin page dies. I am simply trying to change the default index template to something different. Short of changing the URL completely from XXX/admin/homepage to something else, I have no idea how to solve this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? The URL resolvers just finds the first match; so there's no reason why any URL wouldn't work regardless of what follows after it.

Comment: I think the url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)) takes precedence. If I make a change to that line say to url(r'^admin/$', include(admin.site.urls)) then the url(r'^admin/homepage/$', 'homepage.views.index') actually works. But all other admin pages die. This implies I will have to make views for all those admin pages.

Comment: I also think it should just work as long your custom url definition comes before the one for the actual admin in the urlconf (urls.py)!

Comment: 1000Suns, in what way does it "die"? Do you get an exception? Does it raise a 404?

Comment: I get an error saying: NoReverseMatch at /admin/ Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'sites'}' not found

Comment: Haha. @Torsten was right. I just had to put the pattern before the default admin url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should just work as long your custom url definition comes before the one for the actual admin in the urlconf (urls.py):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',      
    ...    
    url(r'^admin/homepage/$', 'homepage.views.index'),
    ...
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `url(r'^admin/homepage$' ...` in this example?

Comment: @JamesKhoury both cases should work. But for what I was trying to do, the above solution works.

Comment: @1000Suns Its just that your post mentioned going to admin/homepage not admin/homepage/ ... seems like very little difference but can be a major issue.